# Can't create/delete/edit items in Public Folders

Tags: exchange

This Exchange 2010 server worked for years unchanged. Client complained that he can't longer delete items in any Public Folder.

I logged in as Domain Admin and started Outlook locally on the server.
I can't delete/create or edit any items either.

Exchange 8.3 (Build 83.6)

All permissions are correct and I already took all standard steps to resolve this issue.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity "\Mass Misses" -User Administrator

Identity                   User                       AccessRights
--------                   ----                       ------------
\Mass Misses               DOMAIN/Users/...           {Owner}
```

Nothing is available in Google regarding this issue.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: `All permissions are correct and I already took all standard steps to resolve this issue` - I really hate statements like this because it tells us nothing. What are the permissions? What are the actual steps that you took?

Comment: Original post? What original post? How could you expect an insightful answer that doesn't just repeat things that you may have already done when you've provided no details about what you've already done?